# Possible to create a user for a specific database only?

Tags: basex

According to the BaseX documentation about [user management](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/User_Management), it is possible to create a set of users with certain permissions (READ, WRITE, etc..). These permissions have effect on what database operations can be executed.

This leads to my question: is it possible to create users that only have access to a certain database?

For example:

```
user 'admin' -> db1, db2, ...
user 'bob'   -> db1
user 'alice' -> db2
```

I played a little bit around with the users and it seems that every user can "see" every database created in BaseX. For Example if `bob` hat `WRITE` access, he can write to `db1, db2` and not only `db1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you link to if you

```
CREATE USER bob
```

bob will have no permissions at all.
Then

```
GRANT WRITE ON db1 to bob
```

The user bob will only have access to db1. 
Note that user management has changed over BaseX versions so on an older version you may have to explicitly GRANT none to bob before granting the more specific permissions.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Can't believe I missed that.